# Fortran does if stop need an endif?

Tags: fortran

In fortran 90, does an if stop statement require a closing endif?

example:

```
if(foo.eq.1) stop
!do some stuff
```

Is do some stuff part of the loop or does stop imply endif as the program is ended?

Comment: Fortran specifies two forms of `if` statements.  Your code conform with Fortran 2018 R1139, if-stmt is `IF` ( scalar-logical-expr ) action-stmt.  It is a single line of code.  An if-stmt is not a loop.  Not does R1139 require an `endif`.

Comment: Fortran 2018, hah! Trying to sort out and update some spaghetti written in the 80s-90s, hodge-podge of 77/90.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are mainly two places (apart from the arithmetic if) where the `if` keyword can be met.

Firstly it is the logical if statement

```
if (condition) statement_if_true
```

If the condition is true, the `statement_if_true` is executed. Anything that follows is not part of the if statement. There is no `then` and no `end if` here.

Secondly there is the if conditional construct

```
if (condition) then
  body with statements
end if
```

The body can contain any number of statements or constructs and must be followed by `end if`. The `then` keyword is obligatory for the construct and the body begins on a new line after the `then`.

Comment: Technically, the first example is an if statement.  The Fortran standard EBNF is if-stmt.  The second example is an if construct with an EBNF of if-construct.  There is no such thing as a logical if statement.  There is an arithmetic if statement, which became a deleted feature in Fortran 2008.  Perhaps, you were trying to make a distinction?

Comment: @evets It is widely called "logical if" to distinguish it from "arithmetic if". And it is a statement too. The EBNF terms are only used in the standard, not in plain language descriptions. You won't find any `if-stmt` in Metcalf, Reid, Cohen and I certainly won't teach them to my students. I did mentiin the arithmetic if and I intentiinalky do not treat it in the answer, it is a useless digression. One has to adjust the level of technical description in the explanations to the level applicable to the audience.  At least in my eyes.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Fortran%22+%22logical+if+statement%22&oq=%22Fortran%22+%22logical+if+statement%22

Comment: Ok.  Well, hopefully, you teach your students correct terminology in their course of study.  In Fortran, the correct terminology is _if statement_ and _if construct_.  Both start with `IF (scalar-logical-expr)`  shouldn't your latter example be referred to as a _logical if construct_ to be consistent with the description of the former example.

Comment: @evets I simply do not agree, there is nothing wrong about "logical if". I think it even was the standard term in F77. Just "if statement" is fine, but you were calling for  `if-stmt`. BTW, I do not teach in English anyway.

Comment: This clears it up, thanks @VladimirF. So in my case we have an if with single statement of "stop," thus not requiring end if.

Comment: @evets "logical if statement" and "if construct" are both widely used in literature at the same time. There is nothing inconsistent about that https://www.google.com/search?q=%22logical+if+statement%22+%22if+construct%22 I can't see how would a minor terminological issue warrant a downvote here.